# Does Expression Blend have a concept of trim/crop?

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

I'm rebuilding the graphic on the left as the graphic on the right in Expression Blend.

The gradient brushes are great for creating reflection effects but how do I now trim the button on the right now so that it cuts off the rest of the reflective circle?

I can **rotate, scale, skew, recenter, and flip** but I can't find trim or crop.

And when I select both the top and the bottom to do "**combine/intersect**" all options are greyed out when I select "combine".

Is trimming the way I want to here possible in Expression Blend or I am reaching the limits of what the underlying XAML could represent?

Or is there an easier way to achieve the graphic on the left?

[alt text http://tanguay.info/web/external/trimInBlend.png](http://tanguay.info/web/external/trimInBlend.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a clipping path?

http://blogs.msdn.com/expression/archive/2008/01/21/clip-path-editing-and-animating-in-blend-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would apply a gradient on the graphics on the right and make it fade to transparent. That way, no need to crop anything.